# How to manually render a template in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

The Discover Meteor book shows how to use the sasha:spin package to show a loading spinner template (`<template name="loading">`) while IronRouter waits for data.

How do I use this same loading template while I'm waiting for a regular jQuery ajax call to finish?

```
var locationInfoByZipcode = function(zipcode, callback){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipcode,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(){
      // Render the loading template. I tried Blaze.render("loading") but I'm not using it right
    }.
    success: function(response){
      // Stop the loading template.
    },
    error: function(){
      callback("error");
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Blaze.render` takes a template and a parent, not a string, so it'd be `Template.loading` and then the parent template you want to render into. You'd probably want to destroy it in the success callback.

What might be a little bit cleaner is putting the HTTP req inside a method along with a reactive variable & calling that method on click. Then, you can keep the loading template inside an `#if reactiveVarIsTrue` type thing in spacebars. Just a personal preference to not use jquery ajax calls if I can help it because they're not very expressive.

Comment: Can you give an example of `Blaze.render`? The Meteor docs give no examples and they don't even state which datatype any of the arguments need to be... `Blaze.render(Template.loading, Template.layout)` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
var locationInfoByZipcode = function(zipcode, callback){

  var renderedView = {};

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/" + zipcode,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(){
      // $('body')[0] is the DOM node object that .render() needs
      renderedView = Blaze.render( Template.loading, $('body')[0] );
    },
    success: function(response){
      // to remove the template you need to pass Blaze.remove() the returned value from the initial Blaze.render() call
      Blaze.remove(renderedView);
      callback(response);
    },
    error: function(){
      callback("error");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You should consider putting this call into a `Meteor.methods` method, and then calling that method from the client.

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: You can call the function and get a response through Meteor's connection to the server. Plus, the function will be a lot more portable.